# How to auto-populate Sequential Guid default value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

**Setup**

I have a `uniqueidentifier` column that's set as the `primary key` with a `Default Value or Binding` of `(newsequentialid())`.

**What Works**

In my MVC project, I can use things like `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and `Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);` to allow SQL Server to take over and use the specified `Default Value or Binding` to automatically generate a Sequential Guid, and this works fine.

**What Doesn't Work**

However, if I write code outside of my MVC project, specifically, in LINQPad, an empty Guid, e.g., `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, is always inserted:

```
Resources.InsertOnSubmit(new Resource());
SubmitChanges();
```

I understand that I can write something like this to insert a randomized Guid value: `new Resource() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }`, but I need a Sequential Guid.

**Why I'm Confused**

I was under the impression that when a null or empty value was passed to a SQL Server column, the `Default Value or Binding`, if specified, would automatically be used.

**Question #1:**

Why is the `Default Value or Binding` being ignored when using LINQPad?

**Question #2:**

How can I make SQL Server use the specified `Default Value or Binding` of `(newsequentialid())` when I don't have access to the MVC attributes noted above?

Comment: Globally Unique IDentifiers by  definition are Random, if they are not then are completely unsuitable for their primary function, providing unique keys from multiple locations. so if you are using Sequential ID's, you are not using a guid its just a hex encoded 128-bit integer

Comment: the Guid datatype is a structure, meaning that it cant contain null, only a default values which is 0, but might try changing it to Guid? which is a nullable guid

Comment: Guids as a primary key are usually a very poor choice. If they are also the clustered index (which is the default) the fragmentation jumps to 99.99% with as few as a couple thousand rows. This means you have to constantly be defragmenting your index. In your case you are using sequential ids which eliminates the fragmentation but also loses the benefit of a guid in the first place. It is now painless to predict values. You might as well use an identity. It takes less storage space, less index space and is easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your second question, SQL Server will ignore the default binding on your column if `NULL` is explicitly specified in the insert statement. Similarly, if your MVC project is generating a default `Guid`of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` then SQL Server will simply insert the value into your table.

One option is to simply generate your own sequential GUID from your MVC project. There are plenty of example of sequential GUID generators in C#. I personally like Alex Siepman solution for sequential GUID you can find it at the following location:
http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2015/06/20/SequentialGuid-Comb-Sql-Server-With-Creation-Date-Time-.aspx

Alternatively, you can create `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on your target table to correctly handle the insert in the manner you want. In your case you want to omit the ID being passed to the table and let SQL Server generate the ID for you. The trigger will look as follow:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoGuid_Trigger ON [dbo].[YourTableName]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[YourTableName]
    (
         -- Exclude ID from column list, SQL Server will generate the ID
         [YourCol1]
        ,[YourCol2]
        ,[YourCol3]
        ,...
    )
    SELECT   [YourCol1]
            ,[YourCol2]
            ,[YourCol3]
            ,...
    FROM    inserted

END
```